# Setting a cookie in functions.php and it gets deleted when working on an other function

Tags: functions, variables, cookies, globals

My first function gets the parameters from the URL and sets the cookies:

```
/**
    Get variables from the URL and set them into the coockie
**/

add_action( 'init', 'set_utm_cookie');
function set_utm_cookie() {

    global $utm;

    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $utm['ip'] = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $utm['ip'] = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $utm['ip'] = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $utm['ip'] = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $utm['ip'] = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $utm['ip'] = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $utm['ip'] = 'UNKNOWN';

    $utm = array(
        'utm_source'   => htmlspecialchars( $_GET["utm_source"]),
        'utm_medium'   => htmlspecialchars( $_GET["utm_medium"]),
        'utm_term'     => htmlspecialchars( $_GET["utm_term"]),
        'utm_content'  => htmlspecialchars( $_GET["utm_content"]),
        'utm_campaign' => htmlspecialchars( $_GET["utm_content"]), 
        'ip'           => $utm['ip']
    );


    setcookie('utm_source',   $utm['utm_source'],   time()+3600*60*24*7,"/");
    setcookie('utm_medium',   $utm['utm_medium'],   time()+3600*60*24*7,"/");
    setcookie('utm_term',     $utm['utm_term'],     time()+3600*60*24*7,"/");
    setcookie('utm_content',  $utm['utm_content'],  time()+3600*60*24*7,"/");
    setcookie('utm_campaign', $utm['utm_campaign'], time()+3600*60*24*7,"/");
    setcookie('ip',           $utm['ip'],           time()+3600*60*24*7,"/");



}
```

The next part is responsible for getting inputs from the contact form of my website and sending an email. if the email is sent ==> send the same email with the cookies saved to an other.

```
/**
    Contact form using Ajax 
**/ 

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_contact_form', 'submit_contact_form'); 

// Send information from the contact form 
function submit_contact_form(){

    // Get the UTM variables from the 'get_the_utm_vars()' function
    //$utm = get_the_utm_vars();

    // If there is a $_POST['email']...
    if( isset($_POST['email']) && ($_POST['validation'] == true ) ) {

        // Get parameters
        $email = $_POST['email']; // Gets the email of the user..
        $email_to = "arik@example.pro";
        $walid = 'walid@example.pro';
        $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
        $message = $_POST['text']; 
        $email_subject = "yellowHEAD Intro: $email";        
        $headers = array(
                'From: '. $fullname .' <'. $email .'>', 
                'BCC:  yonatan@example.pro', 
                'BCC:  gal@example.pro', 
                'BCC:  eran@example.pro', 
                'BCC:  tova@example.pro', 
                'BCC:  walid@example.pro', 
                'Content-type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"; format=flowed \r\n'
            ); 

        // Send email to YH, and if sent - do:
        if ( wp_mail($email_to,$email_subject,$message,$headers) ) {

            // Tells me that the mail has been sent
            echo json_encode( array("result"=>"complete") );


            //Add the UTM variables to the emails text
            $message .= "\r\n \r\n \r\n UTM Campaign: ".$_COOKIE['utm_campaign']." \r\n UTM Medium: ".$_COOKIE['utm_medium']." \r\n UTM Term: ".$_COOKIE['utm_term'] ."\r\n UTM Content: ".$_COOKIE['utm_content']." \r\n UTM Campaign: ".$_COOKIE['utm_campaign']." ";


            // A mail for tova with the UTM paramseters
            wp_mail($walid,$email_subject,$message);

            // An automail for the user 
            //$message_responce = "Hi $fullname, \r\n Thanks for reaching out to us with your inquiry. We have received your e-mail and somebody from yellowHEAD will respond to you within one working day. \r\n In the meantime, feel free to connect with us through our Facebook or LinkedIn or to check out our professional blog. \r\n \r\n Talk to you soon. \r\n - The yellowHEAD Team";
            //$header_responce = 'From: yellowHEADinc.com Team <info@exampleinc.com>';
            //wp_mail($email,'yellowHEAD - Thanks For Your E-mail',$message_responce,$header_responce );

        } else {
            echo json_encode(array("result"=>"mail_error"));
            var_dump($GLOBALS['phpmailer']->ErrorInfo);
    }
        wp_die();
    }

}
```

Comment: You're setting the cookies on ever single page load, without checking if they've already been set

Comment: @TomJNowell so it should look like this? 

`if (!isset $_COOKIE['utm_source']) {
    setcookie('utm_source',   $utm['utm_source'],   time()+3600*60*24*7,"/");
}`

Comment: Didn't solve the problem. but I added an 'if' to every cookie that checks if they are set. tnx.